# Webpacker configuration issues in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, manifest.json

I would like to request for your assistance.

I'm creating a rails app and I'm having issues with the webpacker

My webpack configuration is creating an empty manifest.json

I've tried for 2 days reinstall the webpack and replace it, I've been checking with chat  GPT or Stackoverflow but none of the solutions work

Here is the issue

Webpacker can't find application.js in

```
/home/tony/code/Tonyaguilar10/Proton/public/packs/manifest.json.
```

Possible causes:

1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.

Your manifest contains:

```
{
  "entrypoints": {
  }
}

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet" />
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    **<%= javascript_pack_tag "application" %> ** #this is flag as the issue
  </head>
```

my gem file

```
ruby '3.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 4.0.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.7', '>= 6.1.7.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem "bootstrap", "~> 5.2"
gem "simple_form"
#gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 6.0.0.beta.7'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

my webpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: /
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should look up modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    # Hot Module Replacement updates modules while the application is running without a full reload
    hmr: false
    # Defaults to the inverse of hmr. Uncomment to manually set this.
    # live_reload: true
    client:
      # Should we show a full-screen overlay in the browser when there are compiler errors or warnings?
      overlay: true
      # May also be a string
      # webSocketURL:
      #  hostname: "0.0.0.0"
      #  pathname: "/ws"
      #  port: 8080
    # Should we use gzip compression?
    compress: true
    # Note that apps that do not check the host are vulnerable to DNS rebinding attacks
    allowed_hosts: "all"
    pretty: true
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    static:
      watch:
        ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^6.0.0-rc.6",
    "webpack": "^5.53.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "./node_modules/@rails/webpacker/package/babel/preset.js"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^2.0.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

My manifest.json

```
{
  "entrypoints": {
  }
}
```

I've tried

```
rails webpacker:install
```

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

```
rm -rf node_modules
rails assets:clobber
yarn
rails assets:precompile
```

I always get this warning

warning " > @webpack-cli/serve@2.0.5" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack-cli@5.x.x".

Comment: "I'm creating a rails app" - with rails 6? `turbolinks` is dead, `webpacker` is dead, `sass-rails` is dead, `uglifier` is almost dead, `byebug` seems unnecessary in ruby 3. at least use https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker. but you should just start your project with rails 7 from the start, otherwise, you're creating a very outdated app from day 1.

Comment: I have face similar issue with MAC M2 can you let us know your OS detail?